# SSRS and Firebird Database (ODBC Connection issues in Report Manager)

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, report, firebird

I have a Windows 7 OS (64-bit).

I have data coming from Firebird database, and reports in Microsoft SSRS.
I am able to write queries and successfully retrieve data in the BIDS (SSRS 2008), as well as in SSDT (SSRS 2012).

However, when I deploy the reports in Report Manager in the IE browser, I get these 2 errors:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

(this is when I use the ODBC Connection as a User DSN)

(or)

> ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

(this is when I use the ODBC Connection as a System DSN)

I have installed both 32 bit as well as 64 bit Firebird ODBC drivers; I have used the correct methods to add the 32 bit driver in my ODBC Data Source Administrator using `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

Regardless of the 32-bit or 64-bit ODBC connections, I get the same errors while using the connection under User DSN or System DSN.

Comment: You can't use a UserDSN, as SSRS runs under a different user than your own; as to the error with the system DSN, it implies that you are using the wrong bitness, although if you tried both I am not sure what could be causing this (note: 64 bit DSN is created using `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`)

Comment: I noticed something:

I narrowed it to System DSN; now I am able to test the .fdb database successfully using a System DSN - Firebird ODBC connection in 32 bit;


however I am not able to do the same with a 64 bit ODBC connection; 
the system DSN for a 64-bit Firebird-ODBC connection fails to connect the .fdb database, and hence I am not able to see that System DSN connection in the dropdown list in the Connection Properties window of SSRS Shared Data Sources - 'Use user or system data source name.'   
In all these cases, the BIDS and SSDT work fine, theproblem is only with the ReportManager.

Comment: which drive creates a 32 bit DSN?  Since I have a 64-bit OS, I thought the Administrative Tools create 64 bit DSN, and C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe creates 32 bit DSN.

Comment: On a 64 bit Windows, the 64 bit tools, etc are in`C:\Windows\System32`(!), and the 32 bit tools are in `C:\Windows\SysWoW64`. However it sounds like you solved the problem, as it works with one of the two. You can't use a 32 bit DSN in a 64 bit application, or viceversa; so only one type will work.

Comment: My colleague was able to connect; so I will uninstall and try the entire process. Can you provide me a step by step approach on how to make a System DSN with ODBC connection to a Firebird DB work successfully ?

Comment: can you provide the equivalent of C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe    -    C:\Windows\SysWoW64\______ .exe  may be i will install 32 bit ODBC Driver through that, and use as a system DSN

Comment: They are both called `odbcad32.exe`

Comment: ok, i will try this one now

Comment: I have now installed Firebird Client (fbclient.dll) in 64 bit (previously it was in 32 bit only) , and in the report manager I change the data source properties to the correct data source; however in the SSDT/BIDS in the ODBC connection dropdown list, I do not see the system DSN (64 -bit) created and tested successfully with this Firebird DB; I make some modifications (related to data source connection) in the Report Manager to see report in the IE browser

Comment: Figured out: Posted the answer here:                                                                    https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4bd4715f-1e25-4fb1-9517-ea25c8a35af2/connection-issues-between-firebird-database-and-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices&prof=required

Comment: Thanks Mark for your help