# Connection issues between Firebird Database and SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, firebird, connectivity

ODBC Connection that is used as System DSN is not showing in the SSRS dropdown 'Use user or system data source name' for a data source.

The test connection failed when I try to test the (System DSN) ODBC connection  to  a Firebird database. This is a possible reason why I am not seeing the System DSN.

Is there a way I can make the System DSN to show up in the SSRS data source ?

Comment: Have you tried fixing the connection test problem? Also related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846845/ssrs-and-firebird-database-odbc-connection-issues-in-report-manager) have you ensured it is the right DSN architecture (32 bit vs 64 bit)?

Comment: I have tested the 64 bit system DSN with the Firebird Database (fbclient.dll in Program Files) successfully. I also have a 32 bit fbclient.dll (in Program(x86) Files)  - and the ODBC connection is tested successfully there also with a System DSN.

In the SSRS side I do not see the 64 bit System DSN FIrebird ODBC connection, even though it is tested succesfully - I see only the 32 bit ODBC connection

Comment: what i do is in the report manager side, i change the data source connection to the 64 bit system DSN, and test successfully; this method is fine, but i use one data source in the SSDT/BIDS and another (64-bit System DSN) in the Report Manager

Comment: any suggestion on what prevents the 64-bit system DSN from showing up in the SSRS connection side, even the DB is tested successfully?( Use user or system data source name    in SSRS)

Comment: So you see and use the 32 bit Firebird ODBC DSN? Then **there is no problem**. An application can only see and use the DSNs that match the bitness of the application; apparently SSRS is a 32 bit process.

Comment: yes I do see the 32 bit System DSN with Firebird ODBC connection, but not the 64 bit one, even though it also tested successfully;  so I deploy the report with the 32 bit DSN, and handle the architecture mismanagement error in Report Manager by changing the data source properties to connect to the 64-bit system DSN in the Report Manager.

Comment: Figured out:   Please note that I have a 64-bit Windows 7 Operating System(OS); the SSRS BIDS(2008)/SSDT (2012) can connect only to a 32-bit ODBC System DSN connection, or any User DSN connection, be it 32-bit or 64 bit; complementarily a Report Manager can connect only to a System DSN, and that too only to a 64-bit ODBC connection;  see the solution here   :    https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4bd4715f-1e25-4fb1-9517-ea25c8a35af2/connection-issues-between-firebird-database-and-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: thanks Mark for your kind help; appreciate it.